# Is there a way in R to loop over reading in datasets with the same name but a different suffix?

Tags: r

I have a series of datasets, lets say called dataset1, dataset2, dataset3 etc., and I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to read them in than one at a time?

e.g. instead of:

```
dataset_1 <- fread("folder/dataset_1")
dataset_2 <- fread("folder/dataset_2")
dataset_3 <- fread("folder/dataset_3")
```

I'm envisioning some kind of loop like:

```
for i in 1:3 {
dataset_i <- fread("folder/dataset_i")
```

But this doesn't work.

This type of thing is easy to do in stata, but I'm having trouble finding a way to do it in R.

Any suggestions much appreciated :)

Comment: First u create the list file such as dataset_list <- list(), and loop and store in empty file(initialisation), for example 
dataset_list <- list()

for (i in 1:3) {
  file_path <- paste0("folder/dataset_", i, ".csv")  # Update the file extension if needed
  dataset_list[[i]] <- fread(file_path)
}

Comment: u can also do using table 
library(data.table)

# Number of datasets
num_datasets <- 3

# Use lapply to read all datasets into a list
dataset_list <- lapply(1:num_datasets, function(i) fread(paste0("folder/dataset_", i, ".csv")))

# Access the datasets using dataset_list[[1]], dataset_list[[2]], etc.

Comment: library(data.table)

folder_path <- "folder/"
file_pattern <- "^dataset_\\d+\\.csv$"  # Adjust the pattern based on your file naming convention

# List all files in the folder matching the pattern
file_list <- list.files(path = folder_path, pattern = file_pattern, full.names = TRUE)

# Use lapply to read all datasets into a list
dataset_list <- lapply(file_list, fread)

# Access the datasets using dataset_list[[1]], dataset_list[[2]], etc.